# Is there any API on the browser and nodejs that can convert base64 string to utf8 string？

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

```js
const atob = (encodedString) => Buffer.from(encodedString, 'base64').toString('latin1')
```

Is there an API that can be used normally in nodejs and browsers that can help me convert base64 to utf8 string？

In node.js, we can write:

```js
const base64ToUtf8 = (encodedString) => Buffer.from(encodedString, 'base64').toString('utf8')
```

I need to use this function to process base64 encoded utf8 data-uri in node.js and browser.

Comment: There are two questions here, unrelated at that.

Comment: @Kaiido I have changed my question description now.

Comment: Better, but still too broad. What do you want to do with this "utf-8 string"? There is nothing like an UTF-8 string in a browser, there are only DOMStrings (utf-16), and USVStrings (utf-16 minus surrogates). To store an utf-8 text, you'd need to store it as binary data, in an ArrayBuffer, in a Blob or in a base64 encoded DOMString. But maybe utf-16 is enough for your case and what you really want is just to read your bytes "as UTF-8 text".

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you very much, I updated my description now, I need to use this function to process base64 encoded utf8 data-uri in node.js and browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This node-js code reads the data encoded in this base64 string **"as UTF-8"**. Beware it's not the same as converting "to an UTF-8 string", since JavaScript only supports UCS-2 and UTF-16 strings.

This nitpick passed, there are many methods to do the same as this code in a browser.

The cleanest is to first decode this base64 string in an ArrayBuffer and then read that ArrayBuffer as string, just like your node code:

```js
const b64 = "wqFIb2xhIG5pw7FvcyE=";
const buf = base64ToBuf(b64);
const txt = new TextDecoder().decode(buf);
console.log(txt);

function base64ToBuf(str) {
  const binStr = atob(str);
  const len = binStr.length;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

An other, shorter in code, but implying more IO is to [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) it as text:

```js
const b64 = "wqFIb2xhIG5pw7FvcyE=";
fetch('data:text;base64,' + b64)
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(txt => console.log(txt));
```

And you could also make use of the FileReader API's [`readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText), which might be useful in case you want to support more encodings than utf-8.

```js
const b64 = "wqFIb2xhIG5pw7FvcyE=";
const blob = base64ToBlob(b64);
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = e => {
  const txt = reader.result;
  console.log(txt);
};
reader.readAsText(blob, "utf8");

function base64ToBlob(str) {
  const binStr = atob(str);
  const len = binStr.length;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([arr]);
}
```

There is also the new [`Blob.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) that does convert to utf-8 directly, but from a base64 string, there is very little interest in going that road. Still for the curious:

```js
const b64 = "wqFIb2xhIG5pw7FvcyE=";
const blob = base64ToBlob(b64);

blob.text().then(txt => console.log(txt));

function base64ToBlob(str) {
  const binStr = atob(str);
  const len = binStr.length;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([arr]);
}
```